# Exception after writing to stdin with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to write a Python script to execute Java files and simulate user input. For that I need to be able to send something, read the output and then when I'm prompted again write something again.

I found this to be working partially

```py
def execute_java_in(path):

    print(f"java {os.path.abspath(path)}")
    p = Popen(['java', os.path.abspath(path)], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, encoding="utf-8")

    output, error = p.communicate(input="5789")

    print(output)
    print(error)

    output, error = p.communicate(input="5239")

    print(output)
    print(error)
```

The first input prompts the right response but then an `java.util.NoSuchElementException` is raised. I'm guessing that communicate is writing something to the stdin after my input which is the first letter when the next input should be read. I also tried with `stdin.write()` and `stdout.read()` but then `stdout.read()` blocks all further commands. Has anybody and idea on what else to try?

Comment: I guess nobody can answer this without more information about the java program. But are you sure you don't need to append newlines to the input strings?

Comment: @VPfB The problem is not on the Java side, it can not be changed. The problem is that I have to write to the stdin of the Java file like I would in a shell. I tried it with newlines, did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Is depends on what the Java program does.

You can add a [`timeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) parameter for your `communicate` calls.

You can also provide both inputs immediately :

```
output, error = p.communicate(input="5789\n5239\n")
```

If it still raises `NoSuchElementException`s we can't help you without the Java code.